# VBA Like Operator Doesn't Pick Up Certain String

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some code that searches each cell for certain strings. The code I have will work perfect with every string I try, but for some reason won't pick up a web address I'm trying to search for. Here's the code:

```
If Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Design Review*" Or Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Design Review Protocol*" Or Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Review Protocol*" Then
    If Worksheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*https://extern.website.com/xyz/og/inu/dis/*" Then
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "Yes"
    ElseIf Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Not Required*" Then
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Interior.Color = 65535
    Else
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
    End If
Else
    Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
End If
```

I have a variety of statements like this and they all work fine, but the If statement for the website usually gets skipped over for the Else or ElseIf, even if the cell has the string. Usually in the cell the website would look something like https://extern.website.com/xyz/og/inu/dis/5586574657465836574385, but since the numbers vary I cut off the search after dis/. Any idea why it's not getting picked up?

EDIT: I should also add when I edit the web address so that the numbers are removed, leaving https://extern.website.com/xyz/og/inu/dis/ in the cell, it still doesn't get picked up by the code.

Comment: Could ypu provide an example of a string that was skipped?

Comment: I actually just got it working. I missed a litter in the Like operator so it wasn't getting picked up. thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Would using the [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) function work?

Snippet:

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value, "https://extern.website.com/xyz/og/inu/dis/") Then
```

Full:

```
If Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Design Review*" Or Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Design Review Protocol*" Or Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Review Protocol*" Then
    If InStr(1, Worksheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value, "https://extern.website.com/xyz/og/inu/dis/") Then
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "Yes"
    ElseIf Cells(datanum, myDescCol).Value Like "*Not Required*" Then
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Interior.Color = 65535
    Else
        Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
    End If
Else
    Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(reportnum, 7).Value = "No"
End If
```

Comment: I got it working with the Like function. It was a dumb spelling mistake that was messing it up. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the Like function so I suggested another, glad you figured it out though!